# In Corda's H2 database, do we need to provide our own indexes?

Tags: corda

We are using the default H2 node database. Do we need to provide our own database indexes, or are these created by Corda itself?

Answer (score 1):

When using H2, the indexes are configured automatically using JPA annotations. For example, Corda creates an index for the `vault_linear_states` table as shown [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/vault/VaultSchema.kt#L70):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vault_linear_states", indexes = arrayOf(
        Index(name = "external_id_index", columnList = "external_id"),
        Index(name = "uuid_index", columnList = "uuid")))
class VaultLinearStates(
```

When defining your own state schemas, it's up to you to provide indexes for them. For example, we could add an index to the IOU table in the [Example CorDapp](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "iou_states", indexes = [Index(name="lender_idx", columnList = "lender")])
class PersistentIOU(
        @Column(name = "lender")
        var lenderName: String,

        @Column(name = "borrower")
        var borrowerName: String,

        @Column(name = "value")
        var value: Int,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linearId: UUID
) : PersistentState()
```

Comment: Does this pattern apply to H2 only or any databases i.e Postgres?

Comment: This is an answer just for H2. If you have questions about other DBs, please raise a separate question :)